# Using Spring Cloud Config java.lang.IllegalStateException: No .git

Tags: spring, cloud, config

my application.yml:

```
    server:
  port: 8888

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:[enter image description here][1]
        git:
          searchPaths: cloud-config-repo
          uri: file:///E:/idea/spring-cloud-microservice-example-master/config-microservice/src/main/resources/configPath
```

when using the url:http://localhost:8888/movie/default,i got the misstake:java.lang.IllegalStateException: No .git at file:///E:/idea/spring-cloud-microservice-example-master/config-microservice/src/main/resources/configPath

Comment: https://github.com/kbastani/spring-cloud-microservice-example
 i just use this example

Comment: Maybe it should point to a remote repository not a local directory? :)

Comment: Well, do you have a local git repo at the specified folder ?

Comment: i don't have a local git.

Answer (score 7):

After some days, i found you should create git repository in local machine for this directory: uri: file:///E:/idea/spring-cloud-microservice-example-master/config-microservice/src/main/resources/configPath

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue in my project, i use spring cloud config server

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No .git at
```

to resolve this issue, i configure my spring cloud config server with A to Z, and each and everything fine but facing this problem because I didn't add the **.git** file in my **git-localconfig-repo**, I just open the CMD as shown in the screenshot
[image]

After running the above git commands then change properties file of **config server**

/spring-cloud-config-server/pom.xml

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:/D:/Learning/c7/microservices/spring-microservices/02.Microservice-2x-Spring-boot/spring-cloud-config-server/git-localconfig-repo
```

Example: file:/D:/project-folder-name/configPath

And it also works For Windows I used it like this

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=D:\\\\Learning\\\\c7\\\\microservices\\\\spring-microservices\\\\02.Microservice-2x-Spring-boot\\\\spring-cloud-config-server\\\\git-localconfig-repo
```

Try like this, I hope it will work

Comment: I hope it will work

Comment: Partial answer from this answer helped me in windows. I was struggling with this issue since last 5 days. Totally drained due to this issue. replacing '/' with '////' helped me. Thanks @Fazal a hint in your answer helped me. I had already initialed git repo so only thing i had to do was that replacement.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that a portion of the answer helped you resolve the issue you were facing on Windows. If you have any more questions or face any other issues, feel free to ask. We're all here to help each other!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I faced this issue with Intellij; it failed to refresh my gradle projects giving this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: error invoking git command`
I went to Preferences -> Git and I found that this field is empty: "*Path to Git executable*". Having that field empty means that the default value is usually: "*/usr/bin/git*" while invoking `which git` on the terminal revealed that the right path was: "**/usr/local/bin/git**"
Applying that path didn't fix the issue right away; I had to restart intellij to completely resolve that issue.